# iOS: RestKit enqueued manage object operation blocking UI thread

Tags: ios, objective-c, restkit

I am attempting to load a collection of objects via `RestKit` and have found that this operation is blocking the main thread. Specifically, this functionality is called when a `UIViewController` appears in the `-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated;` message. As long as request is loading, the user is unable to interact with the UI, and has to wait until the operation has completed.

How can I instruct RestKit to execute the request asynchronously (I thought it already was) and stop blocking the main thread?

```
-(void)rtrvArtistsByStudio:(ISStudio *)studio
{
NSLog(@"Retrieving Artists for studio %ld", [studio studioID]);
NSNotificationCenter *notificationCenter = [NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter];

NSDictionary *params = [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%ld", [studio studioID]] forKey:@"studioID"];

NSURLRequest *request = [restkit requestWithObject:nil method:RKRequestMethodGET path:@"/restAPI/rtrvArtistsByStudio" parameters:params];
RKManagedObjectRequestOperation *operation = [restkit managedObjectRequestOperationWithRequest:request managedObjectContext:restkit.managedObjectStore.persistentStoreManagedObjectContext success:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, RKMappingResult *mappingResult) {
    NSArray *artists = [mappingResult array];
    [studio setArtists:artists];
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:nStudioLoadedArtists object:studio];
} failure:^(RKObjectRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Failed to load artists for studio %ld due to %@", [studio studioID], error);
    [notificationCenter postNotificationName:nStudioFailedLoadingArtists object:studio];
}];
[restkit enqueueObjectRequestOperation:operation];
}
```

EDIT:
I should also note that `restkit` is a pointer to an instance of `RKObjectManager`.

RestKit version is 0.20

Comment: Which version of RestKit are you running?

Comment: 0.20.0, edited and added to original question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it was actually my own fault (of course). I have a `UIViewController` category that performs some transitions. During the transition I have the `UIApplication` ignore touch events until the transition has completed (0.2s, very brief). I completely forgot that this existed.

Because I am loading some remote objects in `viewDidAppear` it was still ignoring touch events until that completed. Removing the touch ignore fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The request is definitely being dispatched asynchronously. If you press the pause button in the Xcode UI and look at the threads, what is happening on the main thread and the background threads during the request? That should provide insight into what is causing your thread blockage.

Comment: Turns out it was my own fault, RestKit is not to blame (see my answer). Thanks anyways!